# IOStream operator<< Conversion from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to convert some old C++ code to C# and having difficulty in understanding what the following code does and how can it be converted into C#.

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open(file, ios::nocreate);

if (!fin)
{
    m_iErrorNumber = 1567;
    num = 0.0;
}
else
{
    for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
    {
        fin >> num;  //  <==== THIS LINE IS PROBLEM!!
    }
};

fin.close();
```

Comment: That line is no bitwise operation. It's reading from a stream.

Comment: It nicely demonstrates the power of confusion those operator choices have on novices ;-)

Comment: One of the many reasons I've come to dislike C++ ;)

Comment: Yea the `ifstream` class simply overrides that operator.  Nothing to do with bit shifting.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: I'm not sure why this would bother you considering it makes absolutely no sense to bit shift a stream.

Comment: @Ed: Exactly. So why should the operator do something entirely else, then?

Comment: @Јοеу:  Why not?  Push and pull, it makes sense to me.  It's not like C++ is the only language that overloads operators this way (ruby does the same thing with collections off the top of my head).  I don't know, it's a pretty obvious overload once your advance beyond the absolute beginner level.

Comment: @Joey by that logic, I dislike every language for having constructs which don't immediately make sense before I've learned them. Like C with that crazy `>>` operator that math says means "`fin` is much greater than `num`".

Comment: I feel that the use of `<<` and `>>` for stream operations makes sense; the problem lies in the documentation. Even though it's an overload, it's so common that lists of C++ operators should specify both uses (they should also specify the use of `+` and `+=` as string concatenation operators). I actually learned the stream use first, so I may have a different perspective.

Comment: I see 5 downvotes and not one one comment with '-1 because...'

Comment: Lol'd. BTW, using stream operations chaining instead of string concatenation may be cool idea because of memory usage and performance. It may be very cool if done right, I suspect.

Comment: How about an actual answer everyone??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has probably slightly different semantics from the C++ code, but should be relatively similar:

```
IEnumerable<string> ReadWhiteSpaceSeparated(string filename)
{
    using(var lines = File.ReadLines(filename))
    {
        return lines.SelectMany(line => line.Split(new []{' ','\t', '\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    }
}

IEnumerable<string> ReadDoubles(string filename)
{
     return ReadWhiteSpaceSeparated(filename)
         .Select(s => double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Then you can read `count` doubles from a file with `ReadDoubles(filename).Take(count)`

Comment: Thanks! ReadDoubles(filename).Take(count) will return IEnumerable<double> how can I assign to num which is double.

Comment: I think it should be ReadDoubles(filename).Take(count).Last()

Comment: @johndoe I thought that was just an artifact of you simplifying the code. If you really want only a single element, use `ElementAt`.

Comment: I just don't understand this line in C++ fin >> num; Does that mean it is doing to move the contents byte by byte into the num variable. How can I convert the same to C#. num is a double.

Comment: `ReadDoubles(filename).ElementAt(count-1)` should roughly match the C++ code. It takes the `count-1`th, whitespace-separated double in text form.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ Standard Library overloads the bitshift operators (`<<` and `>>`) to mean "write to stream" and "read from stream", respectively. In this case, `fin` is a file stream; `fin >> num` means to read from the file (until the next whitespace character), parse the data to match the format of the variable `num` (an integer), and store it into `num`.

Comment: A bit more than a direct "store", it is a read which parses a value (of a type matched by `num`) and stores it into `num`.

Answer (score -1):

In this situation the >> operator is streaming data from the file stream into what I assume is a double. Here is how the code would look in C# (change the 8 to a 4 if you're just using a float):

```
using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{ 
    var data = new byte[8]; // temp variable to hold byte data from stream
    for(var x = 0; x < count; ++x)
    {
        stream.Read(data, 0, 8);
        num = System.BitConverter.ToDouble(data, 0); // convert bytes to double
        // do something with num
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `ifstream` uses textual representation, not binary. Your code is also endian dependent, so it's incorrect even for binary files.

Comment: That's not really a port of the OP's code. `ifstream` is reading in text not binary formatted doubles.

Comment: The ifstream's >> operator is overloaded for the basic primitives, so >> myInt would convert the next 4 bytes into an int, while >> myDouble would convert them into a double.

Comment: After looking at it some more I have to concede to CodesInChaos's answer. I'd forgotten about the textual part of the ifstream. Been dealing with binary for too long.

Comment: Even with binary, `BitConverter` using native endianness makes it inappropriate for parsing files. Use `BinaryReader` instead, which always uses little-endian.